# populate table based on option selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, arraylist, thymeleaf

How to get the value of Selected option and use it in the same html to fetch data from Database using thymeleaf and spring-boot.

Here is my code..

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" data-th-action="@{/raw-stock-entry.html}" th:object="${itemReturn}">
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="itemId" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Item Name <span style="color:red">*</span> </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{itemId}" onchange="fetchData()">
                <option th:value="0">Select One</option>
                <option th:each="readyItem : ${readyItemsOnly}" 
                        th:text="${readyItem.itemName}" th:value="${readyItem.itemId}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="Table" width="100%" >
        <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>SL#</th>
               <th>Item Name</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr th:each="itemList, itrItem : ${itemDetails}" th:if="${itemList.itemId} == 2">
                <td th:text="${itrItem.index+1}">Index </td>
                <td th:id="item" th:text="${itemList.itemName}" th:value="${itemList.itemName}"> </td>
                <td th:id="remainingQuantity" th:text="${itemList.remainingQuantity}" th:value="${itemList.remainingQuantity}"></td> 
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

here in my Table I fetch items details from my database, and if I assigned an itemId value then only that item details will show. Thats very fine.

But actually I want to show the item details which is selected from dropdown option at top. I can get the value of selected option using js, but how will I use that value in "th:if" field so that I can show only that item details. 
Is there any better solution of this without using js or using js+thymeleaf mix.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using thymeleaf fragment and ajax.

in your html add following codes.

```js
$('.drop-down').on('change', function() {
  var name = $('.drop-down option:selected').val();
  
            $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
           url: /*[[ @{'/url'} ]]*/,
      data:  {name:name},
      success: function(returnedData){
       console.log(returnedData);      
         $('.details').html(returnedData);
          
     },    
     
     error: function(xhr, exception) {
      console.log(xhr);
                    alert("error");
                  }
         });
    
 });
```

```html
<select class="form-control drop-down" th:field="*{itemId}" >
      .....
            </select>
<div class="details">
<div th:fragment="details">
<table>
......
......
<table>
<div>
<div>
```

and in your controller write code like bellow.

```
@GetMapping("/url")
public ModelAndView getDetails(@RequestParam("name")String name){
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("htmlpagename::details");
   List<Item> itemDetails= repository.findByName(name);// your query result 
    mv.addObject("itemDetails",itemDetails);
     return mv;

}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have used ajax already. I m searching for alternate solution of ajax. and want to know that is it possible with thymeleaf only.

Comment: No. As far as I know only with thymeleaf it is not possible